# Share APK via share option in android

Tags: android, bluetooth, apk, share, media

Hi I'm trying to make a button which share my application through other media like Bluetooth & ShareIt. I tried this

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Share this application");
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    startActivity(sendIntent);
}
```

This works for sharing some text. Now how can I share my apk file or application via this???

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
private void shareApplication() {
        ApplicationInfo app = getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo();
        String filePath = app.sourceDir;

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        // MIME of .apk is "application/vnd.android.package-archive".
        // but Bluetooth does not accept this. Let's use "*/*" instead.
        intent.setType("*/*");


        // Append file and send Intent
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath)));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share app via"));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @AliEsmaeili this is what I'm looking for.